# Lovecraft's Deep Ones and co. in the 21st century

Tags: call-of-cthulhu, call-of-cthulhu-d20, lovecraftian, delta-green-for-call-of-cthulhu

Are there any official (ie. published by Chaosium or its licensees) sources on **what the Deep Ones** (and, secondarily, similarly "human-scoped" creatures: ghouls, Mi-Go etc) **of the Cthulhu Mythos are up to in the 21st century, and how their society adopted to the challenges posed by the advancements of the era**?

I remember having read in Delta Green (an official fork of the CoC universe, as far as I know) that the Deep Ones (my primary interest) have mostly retreated from the affairs and the ever more vigilant and omnipresent, augmented eyes of humanity, having their "job" considered done. Yet DG - itself a bit dated now - is just a take on the possibilities, and I wonder whether there have been others.

Also, if you have an unofficial, yet original theory besides the answer, or you've encountered one, you're welcome to share it.

Comment: How mainstream does the answer have to be?  Would The Laundry setting be appropriate?

Comment: I'm open to anything interesting, and I'd consider The Laundry rather official in the above sense, based on the reviews I've read. (I don't own / haven't played the game yet.)

Comment: As a note below for Cthulutech and The Laundry, I don't believe either are licensees of Chaosium.  They both use different mechanics at least.  Also Pagan Publishing who created Delta Green are making a new version separate from Chaosium's BRP system and updated to present day.  I don't know how they are handling Deep Ones and friends though.

Comment: @mirv120 I don't know about Cthulhutech, but The Laundry even uses Chaosium's BRP system. As for the upcoming new version of DG, I'm looking forward to it.

Comment: @CAA No, but a quick google says even its second edition is 20 years old by now? That doesn't mean it can't be good (on the contrary), but I don't think it would deal with the Mythos creatures' 21st century problems I'm rather curious about, such as everyone having persistent online connection, (multiple) cameras and video-recording in their pockets, geolocation etc.

Comment: there is a german version from 2011, which is pretty amazing for german standards - which includes things like cyberspace. Also one of the adventures in it is about an a.i.  http://www.amazon.de/Cthulhu-Now-Rollenspiel-Jens-Weber/dp/3941976338/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1363992437&sr=8-2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The Laundry](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2011/01/laundry-reading-order.html) setting by Charles Stross has deep ones (BLUE HADES).  They are known about and the occult community has contact with them.  Some organisation recruit BLUE HADES hybrids to work alongside human minders. They are signatories of the Benthic treaty which govern the human/muthos interactions with other sentient races on Earth.  Of course, I do not want to say too much to avoid spoiling the books/game (read: *you do not have BLUE HADES clearance*).

See page 207 onwards in [The Laundry RPG](http://www.cubicle7.co.uk/our-games/the-laundry/).  The information about them is scattered within the books but the main one to read would be [The Jennifer Morgue](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Jennifer-Morgue-Laundry-Files/dp/1841495700).  If you wanted to know more about the world, you can read [Down On The Farm](http://www.tor.com/stories/2008/07/down-on-the-farm) which deals more with how magic works and [Overtime](http://www.tor.com/stories/2009/12/overtime) which deals with a lurking horror breaking through.

Comment: This sounds vaguely interesting, but I'd really appreciate some relevant spoilers, details that would sell The Laundry. ;) (I'm sure you do know [how to hide them](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers).)

Comment: @OpaCitiZen: To be fair, my post was in the paranoid style of the books where knowing too much gets you eaten by things Man was not meant to know.  The whole point of The Laundry is that the Stars Are Right soon (next ten years) so they are desperatly trying to find some way to survive.  Read the two short stories as tasters and if you like them, get the books.

Answer (score 8):

Another unofficial take on the Cthulhu Mythos would be ***[CthulhuTech](http://www.cthulhutech.com/)***. It's set in 2085 and here's the blurb from the product:

> Humanity faces extinction. Alien insects from the edge of our solar
>   system, long hidden behind the façade of reality, descend to enslave
>   us. Hordes of unspeakable horrors roll out from Central Asia, laying
>   waste to anything in their path. The church of the fish-god scours the
>   world for lost occult secrets to unleash terrible forces. Dead gods
>   awaken and turn their dreadful eyes toward the Earth. And within hides
>   a cancer, eating away at the very heart of the New Earth Government.

And the [***CthulhuTech*** wiki](http://cthulhutech.wikidot.com/deep-ones) has this to say about the *Deep Ones*:

> The Deep Ones and the Esoteric Order of Dagon have become a powerful
>   faction in the Strange Aeon, to the point that they field their own
>   lovecraftian war machines.
>
> The EOD has conquered many coastal areas and islands, including
>   Iceland, Newfoundland, Sardinia, Polynesia, Micronesia, most of the
>   Caribbean, Greenland, the Azores, and the coasts of western Africa,
>   Spain, Ireland, Italy, Taiwan, New England, South Africa, northern
>   Brazil.

Answer (score 6):

As noted above, the present defining text of the Mythos in the present day is Stross' Laundry series, and the associated RPG.

Delta Green has already been noted, though excellent as it is, it's definitely a product of its time.

Also  a product of its time is SJGames'GURPS Cthulhupunk, a mashup of the GURPS Cyberworld setting+Cthulhu. I forget the details as it's been some years since I read through it, and bear in mind, it was published way back in '95, with all the attendant divergence of real tech vs. fiction tech of today.

Answer (score 2):

The Delta Green book Targets of Opportunity describes the Deep One Colony on Black Cod Island in Alaska. In addition to being more current than the rest of DG, it shows what might have happened to Innsmouth had it been left to fester a few more centuries.